# Managing RabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I'm new to RabbitMQ and MQ's in general. I'm using the rabbit.js Node.js module to interface with RabbitMQ, so all my application layer is going to mainly be in Node.js. What I'm wondering is, how do I manage RabbitMQ? How can I see everything that's going on with RabbitMQ, from what's messages are left in the queue to general configuration and administration?

I'm looking for something visual, but more importantly, easy to use and simple.

Answer (score 1):

`RabbitMQ` has a `web interface` (part of the `rabbitmq_management` plugin which ships with `RabbitMQ`, but needs to be enabled) that allows you to see the `server`s, `exchange`s, `queue`s, etc.

It's pretty easy to use. One thing I would recommend is to set the time-interval on the graphs to 10 minutes. I find if you set them to longer, say, an hour plus, the information (due to the way it's bucketed, I think) gets a bit wonky.

Check out this link for more info: https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

There is also a `JSON` API that can be used to programmatically determine, for example, how many items are in a particular queue.

There's also a `cmdline tool`, called `rabbitmqadmin` (https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) which can come in really handy for things like setting up test `RabbitMQ` test environments via a `bash` script and things of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

check [JXM.io](http://jxm.io) sources (open source messaging backend for node.js / JXcore) that uses RabbitMQ for multi server integration and there is a nice article showing how to cluster RabbitMQ http://jxm.io/multi-server-messaging-backend-installation/